# Damper pedal for Requiem for a Dream

Tags: piano, technique

This has been bothering me for some time. I have been playing the piano for 3 years so far, and despite all my efforts I am unable to find an answer. It's a bit of a difficult question to phrase, so bare with me.

In "Requiem for a Dream" by Clint Mansell(the difficult version), almost right from the beginning you are required to play whole notes or half notes with your left hand. The right hand is supposed to play alternating A and Bb notes as well as a series of notes an octave lower (Bb, A, G, D). I assume, since it is pysically impossible to stretch my right hand that far that I am supposed to use my left hand for (A, G, D), but then how do I maintain the whole notes or half notes without using the damper pedal? Or am I missing something and am totally wrong in my thinking?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can we please see the music, if possible with your fingerings on it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume this is the passage?

[image: Requiem for a Dream opening bars]

Under the circumstances, I don't think you can play it dry: you'll need to play the latter three quavers (eighth notes) of each group of quavers with the left hand. You will have to pedal with the LH semibreves (whole notes) and minims (half notes), although you can delay the onset of pedal until slightly after the start of each group.

Comment: Ahh, much obliged. It's a relief to know I've been playing it right all this time.

Comment: See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBSUwU8Cp_Q